# Bash: rename beginning of filename

Tags: bash, filenames, rename

I have a couple of files, which look like this:

```
1_150901_AC7GLHANXX_P2258_101_1.fastq.gz
1_150901_AC7GLHANXX_P2258_101_2.fastq.gz
2_150901_AC7GLHANXX_P2258_101_1.fastq.gz
2_150901_AC7GLHANXX_P2258_101_2.fastq.gz
```

... i.e., there are two files that start with `1_` and end in either `_1.fastq.gz` or `_2.fastq.gz`, and the same for two files that start with `2_`. What I want to do is to `cat` the two files ending in `_1.fastq.gz`, like this:

```
cat 1_150901_AC7GLHANXX_P2258_101_1.fastq.gz \ 
    2_150901_AC7GLHANXX_P2258_101_1.fastq.gz \
    > 150901_AC7GLHANXX_P2258_101_1.fastq.gz
```

... so that they are merged and have their prefix removed. I have a lot more files in a lot more folders than this, so I want to automate it. I tried the following code, to no avail:

```
for f in *_*_1.fastq.gz
do
    cat $f "${f/^1_/2_}" > "${f/^1_/}"
done
```

I don't think I know this replacement-method well enough, but it's what I have used in the past for less complicated filenames (when they only have different sufficex, and no prefix). I think that the `^` at the beginning signifies start of the filename, but it doesn't seem to work like I want it to, so obviously I'm doing something wrong. I tried doing some troubleshooting:

```
for f in *_*_1.fastq.gz
    do
        echo "${f/^1_/}"
    done
```

... gives me ...

```
1_150901_AC7GLHANXX_P2258_101_1.fastq.gz
2_150901_AC7GLHANXX_P2258_101_1.fastq.gz
```

... which is not what I thought it would be. Does anybody know how I could do this?

[Edit, clarify non-duplicated question]

This question is different from my previous question in that I also have a prefix for the filenames, and that prefix also exists in the middle of the filename. The other question had a simpler case, where only a suffix was what needed to be renamed.

Comment: In this context, the beginning of string anchor is the `#` character, not `^`. See the [relevant section of the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (you have to scroll to the relevant part of the section that covers the `${parameter/pattern/string}` expansion).

Comment: Ah, okay! Yeah, the `#` does work in this context, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find the "1"s then check for the "2"s
if there are both  cat them together and delete the parts.

```
for f in 1_*_1.fastq.gz
do
      g="2_${f#1_}"
      if [ -f "$g" ]
      then
            cat "$f" "$g" > "${f#1_}" && rm "$f" "$g"
      fi
done
```

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot! I also had to change the for loop to `1_*_*.fastq.gz` because I was only getting the `_1.fastq.gz` files and not the `_2.fastq.gz`, but that was my initial fault in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I were in y our position, assuming there's only files with this format in the directory, I'd go for a procedure like this:

```
$ ls | cut -b3- | sort -u | tee stems.lst # list the stems
$ while read stem; do cat *_$stem > $stem; done <stems.lst
```

Try this in a test directory before you go live, else you'll make a mess of the filenames and it'll be a pain to recover.

Closing notes:

- trick: it's a bit inconvenient here because of the redirections, but it's safer to try out the `while` command in non-destructive mode first, by running some form of `echo "cat *_$stem > $stem"` before replacing it with the real thing.
- don't forget to remove `stem.lst` afterwards
- if it's stable and you need to repeat, you can pipe the stem list directly from `sort -u` to `while`
- (if this question is useful to anyone else in the same situation) if your filenames contain anything weird, put double quotes around `$stem` everywhere in the `while` line